# Rails 7.0.4 のインストールができない (エラー：cannot load such file -- psych (LoadError))

Tags: ruby-on-rails

#### 背景/現状

Ruby 3.1.2 と Rails 7.0.4 を用いて、ローカルに開発環境を構築したい

##### 環境

M1チップ
Big Sur ver 11.2.3
Ruby 3.1.2

#### やりたいこと

Rails 7.0.4 をインストールしたい

#### 実際に出てるエラーメッセージ

`gem install rails -v 7.0.4` 実行時

```
cannot load such file -- psych (LoadError)
```

#### 既に試したこと

rbenvアンインストール後、再度インストールし実行

#### 他におかしいと思うこと

・`rails -v` 実行時、"zsh: command not found: rails" が出ずに以下が出る

```
rails -v
rbenv: rails: command not found

The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.7.6
```

・`bundle install` 実行時

"Could not locate Gemfile" と表示される

■iterms画面（文字列貼り付け）

```
hirokinagai@HirokinoMBP ~ % gem list
<internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- psych (LoadError)
    from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:609:in `load_yaml'
    from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:346:in `load_file'
    from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:189:in `initialize'
    from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:73:in `new'
    from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:73:in `do_configuration'
    from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:38:in `run'
    from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
hirokinagai@HirokinoMBP ~ % gem install rails -v 7.0.4
<internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- psych (LoadError)
    from <internal:/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems.rb:609:in `load_yaml'
    from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:346:in `load_file'
    from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:189:in `initialize'
    from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:73:in `new'
    from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:73:in `do_configuration'
    from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:38:in `run'
    from /Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
hirokinagai@HirokinoMBP ~ % ruby -v
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-darwin20]
hirokinagai@HirokinoMBP ~ % rails -v
rbenv: rails: command not found

The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.7.6

hirokinagai@HirokinoMBP ~ % which ruby
/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/shims/ruby
hirokinagai@HirokinoMBP ~ % which rails
/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/shims/rails
hirokinagai@HirokinoMBP ~ % which gem
/Users/hirokinagai/.rbenv/shims/gem
hirokinagai@HirokinoMBP ~ % bundle install
Could not locate Gemfile
hirokinagai@HirokinoMBP ~ % bundle update
Could not locate Gemfile
hirokinagai@HirokinoMBP ~ %
```

■参考画像

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

> bundle install 実行時
> "Could not locate Gemfile" と表示される

そもそもプロジェクトの準備ができていないのでは？
プロジェクトフォルダ内にGemfileを用意してから、フォルダ内にrailsをインストールしてください。